# Jobs with anacron won't run

Tags: linux, bash, backup, automation, cron

I would like to run two bash scripts daily using anacron in order to backup some data.
Unfortunately I can't figure out why said scripts are not executed. For test purposes I let cron execute the scripts and it worked fine.

`cat /etc/anacrontab` gives

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily   nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly  nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly

1   5   TB_bak      /bin/sh /home/vasco2/Dropbox/Scripts/backup_TB.sh
1   5   key_db_bak  /bin/sh /home/vasco2/Dropbox/Scripts/bak_key_db.sh
```

The output of `ls ~/Dropbox/Scripts/` is
`backup_TB.sh  bak_key_db.sh`

I use Linux Mint Katya. `uname -a` gives `Linux vasco2 2.6.38-8-generic-pae #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 05:17:09 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Why can't these scripts be executed?

Comment: Are the cron.daily/weekly/montly jobs executing?

Comment: Yes, I tested this by putting a script into cron.hourly that writes to a text file.

Comment: For debugging run `sudo anacron -fnd`. Helped me alot to fix my anacrontab. It will force execution, ignore timestamps, ignore delays, dont go to background

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the script name to a very simple name without dot and special chars, both the name itself and in the crontab.

Comment: I replaced the dot of the script name with an underscore. I modified /etc/anacrontab accordingly. Still nothing.

Comment: No underscore either : just rename the filename by "foobar", make sure it's executable and try again. And tatata... Magic ?

Comment: I renamed the scripts to backupTB and bakkeydb, made sure they are executable and changed /etc/anacrontab. They are not executed.

Comment: Make also sure it's chmoded +x and the file's owner is correct Vs. your user's crontab list.

Comment: Thanks, I made sure they are executable. What are correct Vs?

Comment: For example, under Debian, periodic cronjobs are shells stored in the /etc/cron.hourly - daily - weekly - monthly directories, AND shell file names THEY SHALL NOT include .sh or special signs